# Apache installed but not running Debian

Tags: apache-2.2

i have installed apache in debian lenny distro but everytime i start it or check its status it says apache running with certain process id. but when i check the defualt web page (i.e http://server-ip) it gives "It Works"
but when i try my pages it doesnt works

Giving this error "The requested URL /click-to-call.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny3 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 Server at 120.138.20.149 Port 80"

Please help

*in response to questions posed:*

- I have placed click-to-call.php inside /var/www/html if i am wrong then where should I place this file.
- When i try "/etc/init.d/httpd status " it gives file not found
- I have root access.
- I have placed the file inside /var/www/html

Comment: apache itself is working if you got that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you put the 'click-to-call.php' file?
have you tried to put it in the right place like "/var/www/"?
You'll need a root account to have access to this folder (I guess you have :D)

Comment: have the root access. and i have placed the file inside /var/www/html

Comment: The debian/ubuntu default docroot is */var/www/* **not** */var/www/html/*

Answer (score 0):

that's because your click-to-call.php not located inside your apache's default directory

Answer (score 0):

In Debian it's

> /etc/init.d/apache2 status

But we already know apache is running. So, try browsing to:

> http://your.ip.address/html/click-to-call.php